# How to identify what is causing sys% in top?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, top

top on one of hex cores with hyper threading shows the following

```
Cpu0  :  2.3%us, 58.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 38.2%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  4.7%us, 62.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 31.2%id,  0.7%wa,  0.3%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
..
Cpu23 :  4.0%us, 55.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 40.3%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

I checked with sar -I XALL 1  and the corresponding interrupts in /proc/interrupt . Most of the interrupts seem to point to network interface. ifconfig didn't show any errors or retx on the interface. How can we check for these kind of high system usages?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using `htop` instead of `top`. You can navigate the processes that are running on box much more easily and you can drill down to processes that are consuming resource much easier than you can in top.

Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/) to get you started with `htop`.

[image: ss of htop]